# Spring boot configuration overriding not properly working

Tags: java, spring-boot

Spring boot version for my app is 2.6.12.
My project has a dependency towards a library(with spring boot version 2.7.11) with an auto configuration like so:

```
@Configuration
@EnableConfigurationProperties({LibProperties.class})
public class LibAutoConfiguration {
    public LibAutoConfiguration() {
    }

    @Bean(
        initMethod = "checkSomething",
        destroyMethod = "release"
    )
    SomeHandler someHandler(LibProperties properties, ShutdownManager shutdownManager) {
        return new SomeHandler (properties, shutdownManager);
    }

    @Bean
    ShutdownManager shutdownManager(ApplicationContext applicationContext) {
        return new ShutdownManager(applicationContext);
    }
}
```

Properties configuration:

```
@ConfigurationProperties("lib")
@ConstructorBinding
public class LibProperties {
    private final int a;
    private final String b;

    public LibProperties(int a, String b) {

        this.a = a;
        this.b = b;
    }
    
    // getters
}
```

and the spring.factories file:

```
org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.EnableAutoConfiguration=\
  com.lib.config.LibAutoConfiguration
```

This library also has a application.properties in classpath with empty values for the properties

Now in my spring boot app I have my App class:

```
@SpringBootApplication(scanBasePackages = { com.myApp})
public class Application {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        //blabla
    }

}
```

and my application.yml on the classpath with all properties defined under LibProperties configured.

Application fails on startup with:

```
Failed to bind properties under 'lib.a' to int:

    Property: lib.a
    Value: ""
    Origin: class path resource [application.properties] from myApp.jar!/BOOT-INF/lib/lib.jar - 6:0
    Reason: failed to convert java.lang.String to int (caused by java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: A null value cannot be assigned to a primitive type)

Action:

Update your application's configuration
```

As you can see, it does not override the properties from the library from my application.yml and still looks at the packaged application.properties. This does not happen if I switch to a .properties file inside the jar, or use the --spring.config.location to load the yml file.

Anyone know what the underlying issue could be ? I would expect my app packaged .yml file to override properties under lib packaged .properties file.

Thanks

Comment: This is because your are mixing .yml and .properties files. You should use only one type. In this case .properties

Comment: @Mar-Z is there any info about this in the official documentation ?

Comment: @D.Razvan [This might be what you look for](https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/html/features.html#features.external-config).

Answer (score 0):

Spring 3.1 also introduces the new @PropertySource annotation as a convenient mechanism for adding property sources to the environment.

We can use this annotation in conjunction with the @Configuration annotation:

```
@Configuration
@PropertySource("classpath:foo.properties")
public class PropertiesWithJavaConfig {
    //...
}
```